# Deploying Scala to NixOps

Tags: scala, sbt, nix, nixops

I'm trying to deploy a VirtualBox with a Play 2 webservice in Scala under NixOS with NixOps.

I have this machine :

```
{
  backoffice = {
    deployment.targetEnv = "virtualbox";
    deployment.virtualbox.memorySize = 1024; # MB
  };
}
```

On this logical network :

```
{
  network.description = "Test";

  backoffice =
    { config, pkgs, ... }:
    let
        callPackage = pkgs.lib.callPackageWith (pkgs);
        Back = callPackage ../pkgs/Backoffice.nix {};
    in {
        environment.systemPackages = [
          pkgs.jdk
          Back
        ];

        systemd.services.backoffice = {
            description = "Backoffice";
            # Start the service after the network is available
            after = [ "network.target" ];
            script = "${Back}/webapps/bin/play-back";
            serviceConfig = {
              Restart = "always";
            };
          };

          networking.hostName = "backoffice";
          networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 ];
          system.stateVersion = "15.09";
    };
}
```

Where Backoffice.nix is this derivation :

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "Backoffice";
  src = ../../back;
  buildInputs = [ sbt ];
  buildPhase = let
        sbtBootDir = "./.sbt/boot/";
        sbtIvyHome = "/var/tmp/`whoami`/.ivy";
        sbtOpts = "-XX:PermSize=190m -Dsbt.boot.directory=${sbtBootDir} -Dsbt.ivy.home=${sbtIvyHome}";
    in ''
        mkdir -p ${sbtBootDir}
        mkdir -p ${sbtIvyHome}
        sbt ${sbtOpts} stage
    '';

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/webapps
    cp -ra ./target/universal/stage/* $out
  '';
}
```

The VM starts and deploys fine. But when I ssh into it I can't find my Backoffice derivation inside.

If I do locally

```
nix-build Backoffice.nix
```

...it builds without problems, and I can find the derivation in /nix/store on my dev machine.

In the VM, there is a /nix/store/shaXXX-backoffice.service, so it kind of works. But since the backoffice derivation is not present, it does nothing.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the contents of the .service file?

Comment: thank you SO much for this question, it helped me a lot getting my own sbt build running in nixos. One improvement: Use `let userHome = "/var/tmp/\`whoami\`"; sbtOpts = "-Duser.home=${userHome}"; in mkdir -p ${userHome}`. This saves you from having to specify the boot dir, ivy dir, zinc dir, coursier cache dir, etc. individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! What was needed in systemd.services.backoffice :

```
path = [ "${pkgs.jdk.home}" "${pkgs.gawk}" ];
```

Play Framework script is using both to start itself.